# So much data loss in a big udp project

Tags: c#, networking, udp

My code has data loss. I think it's because of one threaded architecture. I have startudp method and it's working in a thread. Also there is datareceived method for adding data to arrays with 1 byte for all. What is the problem that causes %10 data loss. How should I implement udp and datareceived methods to work asynchronously and increase the performance of udp to not losing much data ?

```cs
private void StartUdpListener()
{
    AppBase.MainDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        UDPthreadFlag = true;
        Thread listener = new Thread(() =>
        {
            udpThread();
        });
        listener.IsBackground = true;
        listener.Start();
    });
}
    
private void udpThread()
{
    Debug.Print("udp thread init");

    try
    {
        if (MagneticAnomalyLiveCommunicationModel.EthernetPortNumber.ToString() != "")
        {
            Client = new UdpClient(MagneticAnomalyLiveCommunicationModel.EthernetPortNumber);
            receivedIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, MagneticAnomalyLiveCommunicationModel.EthernetPortNumber);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            while (UDPthreadFlag)
            {                       
                DataReceived();
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "Port alanı boş olamaz port numarasını girerek tekrar başlatınız.";
            messageBoxEthernetControl = ThemedMessageBox.Show("Ethernet Bağlantısı", message, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("ex thread");
        ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

---

```
private void DataReceived()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] receivedBytes = Client.Receive(ref receivedIpEndPoint);
        List<byte> all = new List<byte>();  //Liste eklenir.

        for (int i = 0; i < receivedBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            all.Add(receivedBytes[i]);
        }

        if (all[0] == 170)  //Gelen byte SYNC1'e eşittir.
        {
            if (all[1] == 85)  ////Gelen byte SYNC2'e eşittir.
            {
                if (Crc32Mpeg2Check(all, all[2] + 3)) //len = crc kısmı olmadan uzunluk verisi yani crc'si hesaplanacak veri
                {
                    LengthArray[0] = all[2];

                    for (int k = 3; k < all[2] + 4; k++)
                    {
                        if (k < 4)
                        {
                            CounterArray[k - 3] = all[k];  //Gelen Timestamp
                        }
                        else if (k >= 4 && k < 8)
                        {
                            magneticXArray[k - 4] = all[k];   //Fluxgate X değeri
                        }
                        else if (k >= 8 && k < 12)
                        {
                            magneticYArray[k - 8] = all[k];   //Fluxgate Y değeri
                        }
                        else if (k >= 12 && k < 16)
                        {
                            magneticZArray[k - 12] = all[k];   //Fluxgate Z değeri
                        }
                        else if (k == 16)
                        {
                            sensorIdArray[k - 16] = all[k];
                        }
                        else if (k >= 17 && k < 25)
                        {
                            potassimTotalFieldArray[k - 17] = all[k];  //Potasyum Manyetik Alan değeri
                        }
                        else if (k == 25)
                        {
                            lockByteArray[k - 25] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör Kilit Durumu
                        }
                        else if (k == 26)
                        {
                            heaterStatusArray[k - 26] = all[k]; //potasyum sensör heater status
                        }
                        else if (k >= 27 && k < 31)
                        {
                            KUtcTimeArray[k - 27] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör utc time
                        }
                        else if (k == 31)
                        {
                            fieldRCArray[k - 31] = all[k]; //potasyum sensör field reversal control
                        }
                        else if (k >= 32 && k < 36)
                        {
                            ligthCurrentArray[k - 32] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör light current
                        }
                        else if (k >= 36 && k < 38)
                        {
                            signalstrengthArray[k - 36] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör signal strength
                        }
                        else if (k >= 38 && k < 42)
                        {
                            rfvoltageArray[k - 38] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör rf voltage
                        }
                        else if (k >= 42 && k < 46)
                        {
                            heaterdcvoltageArray[k - 42] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör heater dc voltage
                        }
                        else if (k >= 46 && k < 50)
                        {
                            batterydcvoltageArray[k - 46] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör battery dc voltage
                       }
                       else if (k >= 50 && k < 54)
                       {
                           sensortemperatureArray[k - 50] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör sensor temperature
                       }
                       else if (k >= 54 && k < 58)
                       {
                           boxtemperatureArray[k - 54] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör box temperature
                       }
                       else if (k >= 58 && k < 66)
                       {
                           uavtimestampArray[k - 58] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha timestamp
                       }
                       else if (k >= 66 && k < 70)
                       {
                           uavrollArray[k - 66] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha roll
                       }
                       else if (k >= 70 && k < 74)
                       {
                           uavpitchArray[k - 70] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha pitch
                       }
                       else if (k >= 74 && k < 78)
                       {
                           uavheadingArray[k - 74] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha heading
                       }
                       else if (k >= 78 && k < 86)
                       {
                           uavlatitudeArray[k - 78] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha latitude
                       }
                       else if (k >= 86 && k < 94)
                       {
                           uavlongitudeArray[k - 86] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha longitude
                       }
                       else if (k >= 94 && k < 98)
                       {
                           uavgpsaltitudeArray[k - 94] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha GPS altitude
                       }
                       else if (k >= 98 && k < 102)
                       {
                           uavvelocityeastArray[k - 98] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha velocity east
                       }
                       else if (k >= 102 && k < 106)
                       {
                           uavvelocitynorthArray[k - 102] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha velocity north
                       }
                       else if (k >= 106 && k < 110)
                       {
                           uavvelocitydownArray[k - 106] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha velocity down
                       }
                        else if (k >= 110 && k < 114)
                        {
                            uavabovegroundlevelArray[k - 110] = all[k];   //Potasyum sensör iha above ground level
                        }
                    }
    
                    ConvertReceivedDataByte(LengthArray, CounterArray, magneticXArray, magneticYArray, magneticZArray, sensorIdArray, potassimTotalFieldArray, lockByteArray, heaterStatusArray, KUtcTimeArray, fieldRCArray, ligthCurrentArray, signalstrengthArray, rfvoltageArray, heaterdcvoltageArray, batterydcvoltageArray, sensortemperatureArray, boxtemperatureArray, uavtimestampArray, uavrollArray, uavpitchArray, uavheadingArray, uavlatitudeArray, uavlongitudeArray, uavgpsaltitudeArray, uavvelocityeastArray, uavvelocitynorthArray, uavvelocitydownArray, uavabovegroundlevelArray);
    
                    count++;
                    //Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), ar.AsyncState);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print("------Recive Error");
        ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to combine UDP packets into larger chunks? The first for loop in `DataReceived()` doesn't make sense, as `all` is always equal to `receivedBytes`.

Comment: I didn't write the project and I'm new in wpf and mvvm but I need to solve the data loss problem. What should I do, should I delete that for loop ?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do wih WPF or MVVM, but just with how UDP works. I'm assuming the problem is that the loop (with a `Thread.Sleep(20)` instead of a blocking read operation) is just to slow. Honestly, the code, as it stands, is very poor and needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: If you use UDP you accept that there will be some amount of lost data. The amount of loss will depend on the network, but 10% does not sound completely unreasonable.. You either need to design your application around this, implement your own reliability layer, or just use TCP that is designed to be reliable in the first place. If you are concerned about performance, have you actually profiled TCP, concluded it is insufficient, and know, in detail, why it is insufficient?

Comment: Also, if you just want some computers to communicate I would recommend using some existing network protocol together with some serialization protocol , like gRPC or MQTT+json. Having large tables of if statements like that look like it will be very fragile.